# What is the difference between "grep -c ^b example" and "grep ^b example| cat –n"?

Tags: grep, cat

I'm trying to learn command line better and wondering what the difference between these two commands would be.

```
grep -c ^b example
```

and

```
grep ^b example| cat –n
```

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]. If you want to learn the command line, the best way is to experiment by running the commands yourself using different input files. Questions should show some research effort so I'd advise checking the relevant man pages to find out the purpose of the different options. Man pages aren't the most readable if you're new to Unix, so if you have any issues understanding it, you could [edit] this question to make it more specific (and useful). See [ask] and feel free to take the [tour].

Comment: (-1) Not even the same commands. Two unrelated commands.

Comment: Did you try running the commands?

Answer (score 0):

Ok command:

1. `grep -c ^b example`: Output the count for matching lines for lines that begin with letter `b`, and
2. `grep ^b example | cat -n`: pass the result of the grep command to the cat command and list them with line numbers. The `-n` forces `cat` to list them along with lines numbers.

Example:

example.txt with content:

```
media sound3
media sound1
media sound2
find sound -type f -name sound[0-9] -printf 'media %f\n' > file.txt
find sound -type f -name sound[0-9] -exec bash -c 'echo media bash >> file.txt' {} \;
find sound -type f -name sound[0-9] -exec bash -c "f='{}'; echo media $( basename ${f}) >> file.txt" \;
```

Result from (1):

```
3
```

Result from (2):

```
1   media sound3
2   media sound1
3   media sound2
```

Comment: Yes your right!

Answer (score 0):

Well, according [to the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html), `grep`:

> searches for *PATTERN* in each *FILE*. By
>          default, `grep` prints the matching lines.

and with the `-c` flag:

> ```
> -c, --count
> ```
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching
>                 lines for each input file.

So, `grep -c ^b example` prints the *number* (count) of lines matching the pattern, while `grep ^b example` prints the lines themselves.

As for `cat`, [it's described to](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html)

> concatenate files and print on the standard output

and what the `-n` flag does is to:

> ```
> -n, --number
> ```
>
> number all output lines

Given the pipe and no file names, `cat` reads from the pipe, so the output is the output of `grep`, with line numbers added. Hence `grep ^b example| cat –n` prints all matching lines, numbered.

---

This is different from `grep -n ^b example`, where `grep` adds the line numbers of the matches. `grep` knows the line numbers of the original file, while `cat` only sees the output of `grep` and numbers the lines accordingly.

So, given the input file

```
$ cat example 
bar
foo
basf
```

We have:

```
$ grep -c ^b example 
2

$ grep ^b example |cat -n
     1  bar
     2  basf

$ grep -n ^b example
1:bar
3:basf
```